# Evaluate $\lim _{n\to \infty }n\int _1^2 \frac{dx}{x^2(1+x^n)}$

Tags: integration

Evaluate $$\lim _{n\to \infty }n\int _1^2 \frac{dx}{x^2(1+x^n)}$$

without Taylor expansion.

I tried rewriting as

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} n\int _1^2 \frac{1 + x^n - x^n}{x^2(1+x^n)}dx = \lim_{n\to \infty} n\int _1^2 \frac{dx}{x^2} - \lim_{n\to \infty} n\int _1^2 \frac{x^n}{x^2(1+x^n)}dx$$

The first integral is computable, but I don't know how to continue solving the second one.

The answer is $\ln 2$

Comment: the first integral is computable but the first limit diverges -- which is why it is not a good idea to break it up into 2 diverging parts

Comment: i think this Limit doesn't exist

Comment: @gt6989b Yes... I also thought about the substitution $t = \frac{1}{x}$ but it seems that doesn't help either,

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner It is $\ln 2$, I will edit

Comment: why it is $\ln(2)$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I have the answer for the problem, I only have to solve it

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner: because $\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{dz}{z(z+1)}=\log(2)$.

Comment: oh thank you i see it now,

Comment: That $\lim (A+B) = (\lim A) + (\lim B)$ is valid if $\lim A$ and $\lim B$ are finite numbers. But since $A$ is $n$ times a positive number not depending on $n,$ you have $\lim A=\infty$, so $\lim (A+B) = (\lim A) + (\lim B)$ is not valid in this case.

Comment: However, it is perfectly valid to write
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} n \int_1^2 \frac{dx}{x^2(1+x^n)} = \lim_{n\to\infty} n\cdot\left( \int_1^2 \frac{dx}{x^2} - \int _1^2 \frac{x^n}{x^2(1+x^n)}dx \right),
$$ with just one $\text{“}{\lim}\text{''}$ on the right side.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I got it. Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By setting $x=z^{1/n}$ we are left with
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\int_{1}^{2^n}\frac{dz}{z(1+z)z^{1/n}}=\lim_{n\to +\infty}\left[O\left(\frac{1}{2^n}\right)+\int_{1}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{1}{z}-\frac{1}{z+1}\right)\frac{dz}{z^{1/n}}\right] $$
then by applying the dominated convergence theorem we get that the answer is $\color{red}{\log 2}$.

Comment: I haven't learned about the dominated convergence at my math classes... Could you, please, explain what to do next or what that means and why can it be applyed in this case ?

Comment: @Liviu: the application is straightforward: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem

Comment: The sequence of positive and integrable functions $f_n(z)=\left(\frac{1}{z}-\frac{1}{z+1}\right)\frac{1}{z^{1/n}}$ on the interval $(1,+\infty)$ is pointwise convergent to $\frac{1}{z}-\frac{1}{z+1}$ and in a monotonic way.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{n\int_{1}^{2}{\dd x \over x^{2}\pars{1 + x^{n}}}} =
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{n\int_{1/2}^{1}{x^{n} \over 1 + x^{n}}\,\dd x} =
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{\int_{1/2^{n}}^{1}{x^{1/n} \over 1 + x}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{\int_{0}^{1}{x^{1/n} \over 1 + x}\,\dd x -
\int_{0}^{1/2^{n}}{x^{1/n} \over 1 + x}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{\int_{0}^{1}{\dd x \over 1 + x} -
\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{1/n} \over 1 + x}\,\dd x -
\int_{0}^{1/2^{n}}{x^{1/n} \over 1 + x}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{\ln\pars{2} - H_{1/n} - 
\int_{0}^{1/2^{n}}{x^{1/n} \over 1 + x}\,\dd x}\qquad
\pars{~H_{z}:\ Harmonic\ Number.\ \mbox{Note that}\ H_{0} = 0~}
\end{align}

> Moreover,
>   $\ds{0 < \int_{0}^{1/2^{n}}{x^{1/n} \over 1 + x}\,\dd x < 
> \int_{0}^{1/2^{n}}{x^{1/n} \over 1 + 0}\,\dd x =
> {n \over n + 1}\,{1 \over 2^{n + 1}}\,\,\,\stackrel{\mrm{as}\ n\ \to\ \infty}{\to}\,\,\, {\large 0}}$

---

$$
\bbx{\ds{\lim_{n \to \infty}
\bracks{n\int_{1}^{2}{\dd x \over x^{2}\pars{1 + x^{n}}}} =
\ln\pars{2}}}
$$